# Speeding up a computation involving log of factorial

Tags: performance-tuning

I compute the following:

```
schA[n_?EvenQ] := 
 N[Sum[Log2[2*Factorial[i]*Factorial[n - 1 - i]], {i, 0, (n/2) - 1}]]

schB[n_?EvenQ] := N[schA[n]/(n/2)]

sch[n_?EvenQ] := schB[n] + N[Log2[(n/2)]]
```

I ran the function sch[n] for n = 5000 which takes considerable time to complete.
Is there a way to speed this up? I'd like to check up to one million or higher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relatively new command `AsymptoticSum` does the job.

```
AsymptoticSum[Log2[2*Factorial[i]*Factorial[n - 1 - i]], {i, 0, (n/2) - 1}, 
n -> Infinity] // Simplify;
```

> `Log[E^((-1 + n - 9 n^3 + 6 n^3 Log[n] +  2 n^2 (Log[64] + 3 Log[\[Pi]]))/(12 n))/(Glaisher n^(1/12))]/Log[2]`

```
schA[n_?EvenQ] := N[Log[E^((-1 + n - 9 n^3 + 6 n^3 Log[n] + 
2 n^2 (Log[64] + 3 Log[\[Pi]]))/(12 n))/(Glaisher n^(1/12))]/Log[2]]
schA[10^7]
```

> `1.05447*10^15`

and so on.

PS. The result of the command

```
NMaximize[{RealAbs[
 Log[E^((-1 + n - 9 n^3 + 6 n^3 Log[n] + 
          2 n^2 (Log[64] + 3 Log[\[Pi]]))/(12 n))/(Glaisher n^(1/
          12))]/Log[2] - 
  Sum[Log2[2*Factorial[i]*Factorial[n - 1 - i]], {i, 
    0, (n/2) - 1}]]/
Sum[Log2[2*Factorial[i]*Factorial[n - 1 - i]], {i, 0, (n/2) - 1}]*
   Sqrt[n], n >= 10^6}, n]
```

> `{4.75504*10^-13, {n -> 1.00001*10^6}}`

gives an estimate of the accuracy for big `n`.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that this produces an approximation of the sum, which works for large values of n? I am carrying out experiments in relation to a lower-bound so need exact values. Is there info on the accuracy of AsymptoticSum?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I dont know any info about the accuracy of `AsymptoticSum`. As I understand it, `AsymptoticSum` uses `Series[Sum[
  Log2[2*Factorial[i]*Factorial[n - 1 - i]], {i, 0, (n/2) - 1}], {n, 
  Infinity, 2}]` here, which results in

Comment: $$ \frac{\log \left(\left(\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{5/2}\right)\right) \exp \left(\frac{1}{4} (2 \log (n)-3) n^2+\frac{1}{2} (\log (2)+\log (2 \pi )) n+\frac{1}{12} (-12 \log (A)+5 \log (n)-6 \log (2 \pi )+1)-\frac{1}{12 n}-\frac{1}{240 n^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^3\right)\right)\right)}{\log (2)}.$$

Comment: What is A in the above formula ? Is it Glaisher's constant ?

Comment: @underranrand: I think yes, $A$ stands for Glaisher's constant.

Comment: It stands for Glaisher symbol. As in N[Glaisher].

Answer (score 8):

One can numericize inside the summation to avoid intermediate swell, and also use `LogGamma` to avoid computing large factorial products and then taking logarithms thereof.

```
schAx[n_?EvenQ] := (n/2) + 
  1/Log[2]*(Sum[LogGamma[i + 1.] + LogGamma[n - i], {i, 0, (n/2) - 1}])
schBx[n_?EvenQ] := schAx[n]/(n/2.)
schx[n_?EvenQ] := schBx[n] + Log2[(n/2.)]
```

Compare:

```
In[67]:= sch[10000] // Timing
schx[10000] // Timing

Out[67]= {1.53963, 111253.}

(* Out[68]= {0.001467, 111253.} *)

In[70]:= schx[10^6] // Timing

(* Out[70]= {0.136898, 1.77675*10^7} *)
```

Comment: The `LogGamma` was a nice idea. Now after changing index variables in the second sum from `n-i` to something like `r` then change again to `i`, the sum becomes `Sum[LogGamma[i],{i,1,n}]` which according to Mathematica is equal to `LogBarnesG[1 + n]` and so no explicit `Sum` and maybe Mathematica has cool tricks to compute that function.

Comment: `Sum[Log2[2*Factorial[i]*Factorial[n - 1 - i]], {i, 0, (n/2) - 1}]` results in `Log[2^(n/2) BarnesG[n] Gamma[n]]/Log[2]`.

Answer (score 6):

Since $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} k! = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{n-k}$, another possibility is

```
schAy[n_?EvenQ] := N[Range[1,n-1]] // Reverse[#].Log2[#] + N[Log2[2]]*n/2&
```

Comparison with OPs function:

```
schA[10000]//AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.05008,5.56202*10^8} *)

schAy[10000]//AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000843,5.56202*10^8} *)
```

Example with larger $n$:

```
schAy[10^7]//AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.281514,1.05447*10^15} *)
```